# The norm of $f_n : \ell^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kx_k$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $ \ f_n :\ell^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ such  that $ \ell^2 = \{ x = (x_n)_n,  \sum_{k=0}^\infty |x_k|\lt \infty \}$, $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kx_k$ and $a=(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence of real numbers.
Proof that for every $n\geq 1$, $f_n$ is a continuous and find its norm.

My attempt:
$$|f_n(x)|=\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kx_k\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k||x_k|\leq M||x||_{\ell^2}$$ Where
$M= \sup_n\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|$
Hence $f_n$ is bounded implies continuous.
To find the norm  we have that

$$|f_n(x)|\leq M||x||_{\ell^2}$$
then  $||f_n||\leq M$
but i dont know how to show $||f_n||\geq M$.

Anyway is what I did right?

Comment: How do you know $M$ is finite when all we know is that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: Because i think that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k| \leq \sum_{k=1}|a_k| ^2 <\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From $|f_n(x)|=\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kx_k\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k||x_k|,$ apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the *finite* sum up to $n$. Then use the fact that $\left( \sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \|x\|_2$. This will allow you to establish an $M_n$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n \|x\|_2$.

To establish that this $M_n$ is also the norm of the operator $f_n$, consider the sequence
$$
x_k=
\begin{cases}
a_k,& k\leq n \\
0,&k>n
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,